# Is it possible to remove a whistle-like noise from audio?

Tags: noise

[image]
The speech has whistle-like noises. We can clearly see that the whistle-like noise looks different from other parts of the voice. I searched Google for removing hissing (I don't know the correct term for this type of noise), and a YouTube video said low-pass filter is the solution. But that did not work; It just made the whistle-like noise as if it coming over a telephone line. Is it possible to remove or reduce the noise?

If what I am saying is unclear, here is an [example YouTube video for this type of noise](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tFZKgzg8Dq8). It is not the sound of the waves above, but shows the same type of noise.

PS: I have not tried this, but the method I thought of is like this. To me, the waves look almost the same before and after the noise. So, I could choose the last "normal" wave and repeat it over the noise interval, programmatically.

Answer (score 4):

A very High-Q notch EQ filter can do the trick, although I would probably recommend spectral cleaning to nail this. Izotope RX Advanced Spectral Cleaner is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Free equivalent:

Tokyo Dawn Labs's "Nova" plugin is a combined Parametric EQ/Compressor.  Set the EQ frequencies, with high/medium Q as per ear, to the whistle's fundamental frequency (and its harmonics or irritatics™) and then compress only those frequencies.

Possibly not the same result as spending £££, but might get you closer for zero £.